# Azure App Service TableController Authorized User

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have authentication setup on an Azure App Service (Azure Mobile Service) using Microsoft accounts.

However, it currently allows any user with a Microsoft account to use the service. I'm trying to implement a check against another list (`msaUsers`) for authorized users, but I'm finding that this doesn't always work. I'm currently gauging "success" by inserting another entry in `msaUsers`. `CheckIfAuthorized()` is called in `GetItem()`, `PostItem()`, `PatchItem()`, etc. But I find that it doesn't always insert a new item for some reason. I've also seen a case of double entry.

Why isn't this working? If there's a better way to do this, I'd also like to know.

```
    MobileAppContext context;
    EntityDomainManager<MSAAccountItem> msaUsers;
    JToken userInfo;

    public async Task CheckIfAuthorized()
    {
        if (userInfo == null)
        {
            //Get the current logged in user
            MicrosoftAccountCredentials msCreds = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(Request);
            var c = new HttpClient();
            var resp = await c.GetAsync("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/?method=GET&access_token=" + msCreds.AccessToken);
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            userInfo = JToken.Parse(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            string id = string.Empty;
            string name = string.Empty;
            if (userInfo["id"] != null) { id = userInfo["id"].ToString().Trim(); }
            if (userInfo["name"] != null) { name = userInfo["name"].ToString().Trim(); }

            msaUsers = new EntityDomainManager<MSAAccountItem>(context, Request);
            var efe = from wefe in msaUsers.Query() where wefe.mSAAccountItemUserId == id select wefe;
            if (!efe.Any())
            {
                //not authorized, maybe throw an exception.
            }
            //if (!efe.Any())
            //{
            //    await msaUsers.InsertAsync(new MSAAccountItem()
            //    {
            //        mSAAccountItemUserId = id,
            //        mSAAcountUserName = name,
            //        PersonItemId = string.Empty
            //    });
            //}
        }
    }
```

**Edited** to show the check if user is in `msaUsers` (authorized)

Comment: According to your codes, we couldn't understand your logic clearly. Do you use azure mobile app easy auth with MSA? Besides, could you please tell me how you check if the user have authorized? Your codes just insert the user infor to the database.

Comment: Yes, easy auth with MSA. Please see updated code. I posted the insert version of the code because I was seeing an inconsistency on when a new entry was inserted--by extension, possible inconsistency on the authorization check.

Comment: In my opinion, I  think check the user is authorized in every request is not make sense. This will make the database treat too many select. I suggest you could consider designing a custom user authorized logic in your mobile backend. In the mobile backend, you will firstly check the user authorized from the database, then return the access token to the client to access your backend resources. About how to design custom authorized, you could refer to this [article](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.